# Laravel 4 - group by and search by MySQL YEAR()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a problem in a query I'am making in Laravel.

My query looks like this:

```
<!-- Select all event in this year -->
$thisYear = test::where('id', '=', $id)
        ->where('YEAR(start)', '=', date("Y"));

<!-- Group all events by year -->
$years = test::where('id', '=', $id)
        ->groupBy('YEAR(start)');
```

In the first code I would like to get all the events that there is in this year (2013)

In the second I would like to group all events in Years.

Hopes somebody can help.

Regards, Andreas

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for DB::raw(). I think the following should work.

```
$thisYear = test::where('id', '=', $id)
    ->where(DB::raw('YEAR(start)'), '=', date('Y'));
```

Comment: Thanks - I had looked at raw queries, but couldn't quite understand them:-) Yours worked like a charm:-)